# Jmeter Regular expression for an output

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting an output like below from JDBC request response

[image]

And below is the regex I am trying.. but it is not working

For Batch Id

[image]

For file 
((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([*]+)([a-zA-Z]+)([*.][0-9]+)[_.][0-9]+[.][a-z\s]+)){6}

Comment: This is not clear. Batch ID is just a 5 digit string, right? Then the pattern is `^[0-9]{5}$`, and for file, it is something like `^UG_DECL_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{3}\.xml$`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need Regular Expression Extractor there, you have **Variable Names** section in the [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

Given you configure it like:

[image: JDBC Variable Names]

You will get the following JMeter Variables:

```
batch_id_1=47649
file_name_1=UG_DECL_2017_06_21_006.xml
batch_id_2=47648
file_name_2=UG_DECL_2017_06_21_005.xml
etc.
```

You will be able to see all generated JMeter Variables using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

So you will be able to access:

- first batch_id as `${batch_id_1}`
- second batch_id as `${batch_id_2}`
- third batch_id as `${batch_id_3}`
- etc.

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more details.